# Is it possible to determine what part of a stored procedure is currently executing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, dmv, trace

Say I have a stored procedure like this (assume that the table schemas are fine):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_MyProc
AS

INSERT MyTable SELECT Col1 FROM Table1

INSERT MyTable SELECT Col2 FROM Table2

INSERT MyTable SELECT Col3 FROM Table3
```

Assuming that these end up being big inserts that can take several minutes each, is it possible to determine which one is currently running from within the context of a stored procedure?

I know how to find what stored procedure is running, I'm just looking to see if there's a way to get more granular without having to add PRINT or other tracing statements in there.  Is there maybe a way to make the statements show up in a trace?

Comment: Run in SSMS debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow along with either a [SQL Server Trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx) or [Extended Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).

You can watch completed statements and/or batches, and that should give you the granularity you are looking for.

[SP:StmtCompleted Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I get this done through DMV's as you can see on the below script:

(it is part of a more detailed script, but I just extracted the part relevant to you in this question)

```
SELECT
----------------------------------------------------------------
-- get the query         - what command we are running inside the stored procedure 
-- and the parent query  - the the stored procedure 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
SUBSTRING (st.text 
                , (CASE WHEN er.statement_start_offset > DATALENGTH(st.text) 
                    THEN 0 ELSE er.statement_start_offset/2 END)+1
                , (CASE WHEN er.statement_end_offset <= 0 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
                    ELSE er.statement_end_offset 
                    END - CASE WHEN er.statement_start_offset > DATALENGTH(st.text) 
                        THEN 0 ELSE er.statement_start_offset/2 END)
                    + 1
                ) AS QUERY
    , st.text AS PARENT_QUERY
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions es
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec ON es.session_id = ec.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests er ON es.session_id = er.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON es.security_id = sp.sid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks ota ON es.session_id = ota.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_threads oth ON ota.worker_address = oth.worker_address
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) AS st
```

You can see on the example below, it is doing an `insert` inside the stored procedure.

[image]